# IguanaTex and TikZ

Tags: latex, tikz

I'm experimenting with importing some tikzpicture into a PowerPoint using IguanaTeX.

This is the code I am experimenting with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50,local bounding box=picture, baseline=(picture.south),
    declare function={binom(\k,\n,\p)=\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!)*\p^\k*(1-\p)^(\n-\k);}
]

\begin{axis}[
    samples at={0,...,40},
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=1
    },
    ybar=0pt, bar width=1
]
\addplot [fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.5] {binom(x,40,0.2)}; \addlegendentry{$p=0.2$}
\addplot [fill=orange, fill opacity=0.5] {binom(x,40,0.5)}; \addlegendentry{$p=0.5$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note to get it to appear correctly, you need to change from the default DVI to pdflatex in IguanaTeX.

Firstly, the graph appears BUT there is some unnecessary whitespace that occurs at the bottom. As such, the resulting graphic is too large for the slide. How can I remove this?

Secondly, how can I change the axes etc. to be displayed in white, instead of the default black, so I can see the graph on a PowerPoint slide with a black background?

Answer (score 0):

- you can avoid the space between your graph and the axis by setting `ymin=0`
- to change axis, labels, legend etc. to white, you can make the following adjustments:

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

  \pgfplotsset{
    axis line style={white},
    every axis label/.append style ={white},
    every tick label/.append style={white}, 
    every axis legend/.append style={white,fill=black},
    every axis/.append style={tick style={white}}
  }
  
\pagecolor{black}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50,local bounding box=picture, baseline=(picture.south),
    declare function={binom(\k,\n,\p)=\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!)*\p^\k*(1-\p)^(\n-\k);}
]

\begin{axis}[
    samples at={0,...,40},
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=1
    },
    ybar=0pt, bar width=1,
    ymin=0,
]
\addplot [fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.5,draw=white] {binom(x,40,0.2)}; \addlegendentry{$p=0.2$}
\addplot [fill=orange, fill opacity=0.5,draw=white] {binom(x,40,0.5)}; \addlegendentry{$p=0.5$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]